# Spring Security 3.0 with jdbc

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc, spring-security

I read the "Spring Security 3 database authentication with Hibernate"! But I don't know how I should implementate it into my project!

- In which document I have to set the password/username/drivers/url for the database?
- I have different column titles like OPERATOR_ID/USR_ID/PASSWORD

OPERATOR_ID should be the login name, USR_ID the role and the password for the login

Please, maybe you could post an example which implements my questions? Maybe for a checkout or a *.war file?

Comment: [Here is a nice post for this problem][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068593/spring-security-java-config-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any configuration as such for doing this. You have to implement the `UserDetailsService` which has only one method `loadUserByUsername` to load the user and you have to implement the same to load your user information from your database using hibernate.

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e1679)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to configure a [JDBCDaoImpl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) bean which takes a Datasource as a parameter. How you retrieve the Datasource is up to you, you may grab it from the app server or use something like Spring's DriverManagerDatasource Here is some (pseudo) config

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName"><value>your.driver.classname</value></property>
  <property name="url"><value>yourDatabaseUrl</value></property>
  <property name="username"><value>yourUsername</value></property>
  <property name="password"><value>yourPassword</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="dao" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
  <property name="DataSource" ref="datasource" />
 ...
</bean>
```